# How can i delete "#gosetup" lines in GoLand?

Tags: go, goland

How can i delete "#gosetup" lines in GoLand?  "#Gosetup" lines four times in output. I want to hide or delete these lines.

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/n0x/go #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /tmp/___go_build_first_go /home/n0x/Desktop/goProjects/first.go #gosetup
/tmp/___go_build_first_go #gosetup
```

They are in output. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwFtk.png)

Comment: Default description of what?

Comment: If you mean #gosetup lines, there's no way to hide them. Why do they bother you?

Comment: What are you talking about? What is "default description"?

Comment: look at picture there is output and other "#gosetup" lines? Output is ok. But i want to hide #gosetup lines

Comment: What OS and IDE version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

YouTrack has an [IDEA-219274](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219274) task for adding foldings in the terminal. The workaround is to disable PTY mode. Here are the steps.

1. Open `Help > Find Action...`
2. Type Registry and hit Enter.
3. Find `go.run.processes.with.pty` there and turn it off. It looks like this.

But please keep in mind that the workaround can cause problems with run configurations like failing green tests or vice versa, never finishing debug sessions, and so on. If you notice weird IDE behavior related to console output, please enable the registry option back.

It looks like this.

[image]